# SLICK: как поставить ограничение на количество слайдеров

Tags: jquery, slick.js, slider-slick.js

Slick должен работать если слайдеров не меньше 4 и не больше 8. В противном случае Slick работать не будет. Как можно реализовать это ограничение на работу Slick.

Если можно, пожалуйста, покажите пример.

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }

  ]
});
```

Comment: То есть, у вас больше 4х блоков с классом _responsive_?

Comment: идея в том, что количество блоков может меняться, слик НЕ должен работать, если блоков  > 8.

Comment: `if ( $('.responsive').length > 3 && $('.responsive').length < 9 ) { //slick  тут }` - если блоков больше 3х и меньше 9 (от 4 до 8) - будет работать slick

Comment: спасибо. позвольте еще спросить. А как сделать так что даже если блоков больше 8, слик работает, но паказывает только не больше 8 блоков?